# How to store a List of Structure data in a Vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to store list of structure data in a vector and that data comes from a request payload as:

```
{
"Id":"1",
"Name":"name1",
"Salary":"10000",
"Contact":"1937282912"
}
```

I have the following structure declaration in js folder.

```
struct data {
    string id;
    string name;
    string salary;
    string contact;
};

struct data1 {
    vector<data> vect;
    void put();
};
```

Then I have a method definition for the above structure:

```
void data1::put()
{
    vector<string> details;
    for(int i=0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        details.push_back(vect[i].id);
        details.push_back(vect[i].name);
        details.push_back(vect[i].salary);
        details.push_back(vect[i].contact);
    }
}
```

Then there is a method defined in another structure (in different folder called bk folder) which is taking all data from payload as follows:

```
static data dglobal;
static data1 d1global;
string getData(string &payload) {
   data dlocal;
   dglobal=dlocal;
   data1 d1local;
   d1global=d1local;

   // I am making JSON object for accepting JSON data from payload then

    string sid=jsonobject["id"]....;

    string name=jsonobject["name"]...;
    string salary=jsonobject["salary"]...;
    string contact=jsonobject["contact"]..;
    dglobal.id = did;
    dglobal.name = name;
    dglobal.salary = salary;
    dglobal.contact = contact;
    d1global.vect.push_back(dglobal);
    d1global.put();
}
```

Hey guys do not focus above way of accepting JSON data because everything okay with that I just want to store all data which coming from request payload.Each time when I hit URL from rest client there is always erase previous data and store recently hit data but I want to keep all data which is already store and currently Storing data,how can I do this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no question is asked.

Comment: @Peter Sounds like a good fit for "needs clarity or detail".

Comment: @Peter, I want to ask you that I am able to store only one data in a vect and when I want to store new data then previous data erase automatically with above way do you have another way to do this thing?

Comment: `d1global=d1local` wipes out previous data because `d1local` has nothing in it

Comment: So should I skip this process,d1global=d1local?